# Import another package along with a SPM Library

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Imagine this scenario when your `App` project uses two custom libraries

```
.xcworkspace
|- App.xcodeproj
|- LibraryA.xcodeproj
|- LibraryB.xcodeproj
```

And since in this case we are working with Xcode frameworks one could add the following to the `LibraryB` header file:

```objectivec
#import <LibraryA/MyLibraryA.h>
```

and now not only there is no need to import `LibraryA` in the source od `LibraryB`, but also every time you import `LibraryB` inside your `App` source files, the `LibraryA` gets imported along with it, which can be very convenient.

The same applies to the default Foundation import one can find in an Xcode framework header:

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Now with SPM, I need to manually import Foundation everywhere I use it.

**Q: Is this possible to achieve the same result when using SPM packages exclusively?**

I haven't found any resources on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expose import to your whole package you can use `@_exported` attribute inside of any of your swift file:

```swift
@_exported import Foundation
```

More info about this in next discussion: https://forums.swift.org/t/package-manager-exported-dependencies/11615